# Threads get scrambled during execution

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

In the following code segment I create 3 threads and give them a number to keep track which one's which. When I execute the program, the output is as expected except that the threads are ordered randomly. I would've expected them to show up in the same order as they're created & started (1-2-3), instead I get a scrambled result every time.

Why is this?

A `PrintTask` object creates a random `sleep` time and prints a message when it's done sleeping. The code is straightforward so I won't post it. The same thing occurs when I use an `ExecutorService` instead of separate thread objects.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new PrintTask("Thread 1"));
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new PrintTask("Thread 2"));
    Thread thread3 = new Thread(new PrintTask("Thread 3"));

    System.err.println("Starting threads");

    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
    thread3.start();

    System.err.println("Threads started, main ends\n");
}
```

Output:

> Thread 2 going to sleep for 4907
>
> Thread 1 going to sleep for 4779
>
> Thread 3 going to sleep for 537
>
> Thread 3 done sleeping
>
> Thread 1 done sleeping
>
> Thread 2 done sleeping

Comment: Why do you think they would appear in order? There is no guarantee about the order in which threads are given time slices

Comment: The whole purpose of threads is to perform independent tasks. If you want the tasks to be performed in a specific order you would use a  loop, not create threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How threads are scheduled to run depends on many factors, including any framework schedulers, OS scheduler, hardware, etc. In the absence of any explicit coordination you should never rely on a certain ordering of operations among concurrently executing threads. It can very well happen that a thread is taken off the CPU by the scheduler between starting and actually executing the first instruction.

Answer (score 4):

> I would've expected them to show up in the same order as they're created & started (1-2-3)

No, order of thread execution is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

The only guarantee you have is that ([JLS 17.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5-300)):

> A call to start() on a thread happens-before any actions in the started thread.

But there is no guarantee when several threads are involved so you will need to use some form of synchronization to get the desired output.

Comment: I had tried it with an `ExecutorService` using the `execute()` method, but that didn't make a difference. I've tried it with `submit()` as well but that didn't make a difference either.

Answer (score 1):

> I would've expected them to show up in the same order as they're created & started (1-2-3)

No such guarantee is provided.